# wordpress styling issues with custom theme programmed by someone else

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to work on a wordpress theme custom made by someone else who is no longer available to answer questions about this so I am turning to you all. I have read a lot of articles but seem unable to resolve the issue. The page in question is live and it is here - https://fourthwalljobs.com/covid-19-resources-for-artists/

IF you code inspect, you will see the paragraph about "unemployment" is supposed to be a red background in that area but isnt. The pseudo is set but doesnt seem to affect anything. Can anyone help shed light on what the issue that is blocking that from occurring seems to be and how I fix that? I prefer to not have to start overriding things on individual pages using the "!important" tag.

Additionally all of the links (which are black and underlined) should be showing as blue color but obviously are not.

Comment: The only pseudo-element I see setting a red background is `::selection`. When selecting the text, it appears with a red background. If you want ALL `<strong>` tags to have a red background, add a CSS rule for `strong { background-color: #ff4f57;  }`

Comment: For all links in your page, you should add this to your stylesheet: .container a {color:blue;}

Comment: thanks. Any ideas why this is not working from the editor when using the pages section of the wordpress editor?

Comment: correct, the pseduo it added was:
::selection {
    background: #ff4f57;
    color: #fff; when i asked it to make that section red